# Isolating partial derivative from an implicit equation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a basic problem in Mathematica 11.0 which has puzzled me for a while. I want to calculate `y'[x]` knowing that `Cos[x + Sin[y]] =Sin[y]`. I first calculate the derivative w.r.t. `x` but, when I trie to isolate the partial derivative I get an error message. The code I used is the following:

`In[23]:= Dt[Cos[x + Sin[y]] ==  Sin[y], x]`

`Out[23]= sin(x+sin(y)) (-(cos(y) \[DifferentialD]y/\[DifferentialD]x + 1))==cos(y) \[DifferentialD]y/\[DifferentialD]x`

`In[24]:= Solve [%, \[DifferentialD]y/\[DifferentialD]x]`

`Error: \[DifferentialD]y/\[DifferentialD]x is not a valid variable.`

I tried changing the name of `\[DifferentialD]y/\[DifferentialD]x` too, but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dt[Cos[x + Sin[y]] == Sin[y], x] /. {Dt[y, x] -> dydx}
Solve[%, dydx]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've been looking for. Why it needs the substitution?

Comment: According to the documentation, `Solve` "attempts to solve the system expr of equations or inequalities for the variables".  See the error msg you reported (above).